# yii Criteria only one row in result

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cgridview

I want to show some Calculated Values in CGridView, but it only shows **ONE** row in CGridView

The function:

```
public $Name;
public $ calculatedSum;

public function listSum()
{
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->select = 'Name as Name,'
                . 'sum((wert1-wert2-wert3-wert4)*24) AS calculatedSum,'
        return new CActiveDataProvider ( $this, array (
                'criteria' => $criteria));
}
```

When I delete the `AS calculatedSum` part of the query it shows all results, but with the `AS calculatedSum` part it only shows one result in CGridView. But I need the `AS calculatedSum` to show the calculated Field in the view.

Anybody have an idea for a solution ?

Comment: what about this? `$criteria->select = 'Name Name ,sum((wert1-wert2-wert3-wert4)*24) calculatedSum'` ?

Comment: calculatedSum is not in the DB, i need the "AS calculatedSum" to index it in GridView

Comment: I know, The point here is that I removed additional `,` and also removed `AS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$criteria->select = 'Name as Name,'
     . '((wert1-wert2-wert3-wert4)*24) AS calculatedSum,'
```

Don't use the sum function. That sums up all columns, and without group by (which also isn't needed) will always cause you to have just one row. All you need is simple arithmetic, as you have inside the parenthesis.